# How can I extract complete numbers (e.g. 10 instead of 1, 0) from a txt file and add them to a list

Tags: python, txt

```
#Open the text file in read mode to extract integers
outfile =  open(r'/Users/alfonsomartinezpetz/Desktop/Numbers_in_text.txt', 'r')

#List that will store the numbers 
processed_list = []

#For loop that reads one line after the other
for line in outfile:


    #Nested for loop to check for integers
    for i in line:

        
        #if statement that checks for numbers only
        if i.isdigit() == True:
  
            
            #Adds numbers to the list
            processed_list += i

print(processed_list)

outfile.close()
```

#For example the txt file has this:

Donec sit amet ligula eu tellus venenatis 10 maximus vel vel lectus. Donec pretium risus eu odio semper, id placerat felis luctus. Maecenas commodo mauris vitae augue congue fermentum. Sed efficitur tincidunt elit, nec elementum orci tempus vel. Aliquam tempor ligula nisi. Proin non elit at lorem ornare faucibus a at turpis. Pellentesque 15 molestie aliquam quam vel faucibus.

My current method adds the numbers like so [1,0,1,5, ...] I'm looking for [10, 15, ...] preferably with no imports, maybe a sort of strip or split? I've tried those but it still nets the same list.

Comment: Please post representative contents of the file as formatted text in your question itself. Do not link to the file. Links rot.

Comment: Itereting directly in the line, the inner for loop will iterate through each char. So, as first step in this for loop, do `line = line.split(" ")` and then the loop with iterate through a list.

Comment: separate from your main question here, but it is better practice to use `... is True` rather than `... == True` when doing comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
for line in outfile:
    processed_list += [int(s) for s in line.split() if s.isdigit()]
```

However, this will only extract positive integers.
If you want to consider floats and/or negative numbers, I would look at using regex.

Answer (score 0):

You code adjusted to iterate through a list:

```
#Open the text file in read mode to extract integers
outfile =  open(r'/Users/alfonsomartinezpetz/Desktop/Numbers_in_text.txt', 'r')

#List that will store the numbers 
processed_list = []

#For loop that reads one line after the other
for line in outfile:
    line = line.split(' ') #added

     #Nested for loop to check for integers
     for i in line:

        #if statement that checks for numbers only
        if i.isdigit() == True:

        
        #Adds numbers to the list
        processed_list += i

print(processed_list)

outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than pulling out each character and checking if it is a digit, pull out each word (separated by a `" "`) and check those.

```py
...
words = line.split(" ")
for word in words:
    try:
        processed_list.append(int(word))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

You may also want to do some cleanup on `word` in that loop in case it ends with a special character. `int()` won't work if it is `'5.'` or `'5,'`